# How to increase Compression Memory for ECW Opacity Builder

Tags: erdas-imagine, ecw, transparency-opacity

I am attempting to build opacity within an ECW file using ECW_Opacity_Builder.exe from APOLLO Essential Utilities 2014, which has worked flawlessly many times before.

When attempting to build opacity within a 107 GB (1.5 TB uncompressed) 3 band ECW the tool returns an error:

> Could not allocate enough memory Max Compression Memory Cache Limit
>   2.0 GB is too low, please set above 2.2 GB

Neither of the two GDAL variables seem to make any difference:

```
ECW_CACHE_MAXMEM=4294967296
ERM_ECWJP2_CACHE_MAXMEM=4294967296
```

I have tried the obvious:

```
Max_Compression_Memory_Cache_Limit=4294967296
MaxCompressionMemoryCacheLimit=4294967296
```

I have searched the registry for any keys containing ECW and Compression to no avail and even in desperation searched the [online documentation](https://hexagongeospatial.fluidtopics.net/book#!book;uri=a0a85cbbded4731b04298eb4864981e0;breadcrumb=04c8ac6eb8874db3cbb6228787ccbf27-febc224a3a3b54dc2ab701cb28074661) for any hints to utilities, registry keys or system variables that could help with no success. The method for increasing the size of the cache is not obvious or well documented...

Does anyone know how to increase the `Max Compression Memory Cache Limit` for this utility?

Note: the size of the image is not the problem, I've done larger images previously, up to 2.2 TB uncompressed.

Comment: I found restarting the computer worked for me.